# Does Unruh radiation potentially explain the Paradox of 'apparent non-radiation of charged particles in a gravitational field'?

Tags: general-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, hawking-radiation, unruh-effect

The Wikipedia entry on 'Paradox of radiation of charged particles in a gravitational field' does not mention Unruh or Hawking radiation, but I don't see why they wouldn't provide a solution....

Perhaps we here on Earth DO radiate extremely weak, long-wavelength radiation....

Answer (score 1):

Unruh radiation is a quantum effect. The paradox of radiation in a gravitational field exists even in classical 19th century electromagnetism. Therefore they are unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is exactly what you are searching for, let me know in the comment if it is the case or not and I will change or delete this answer accordingly.

The key to answering this question regarding the possible link between the Unruh effect and the electron-on-earth paradox is to see what is in the referential of what. The Unruh effect says that for an accelerated observer, the non-accelerated vacuum is filled with a non-zero number of particles: this is the relativity of the concept of the number of particles with the referential. One can resume the Unruh effect with these three equalities:
\begin{align}
N_\text{acc/us} &= \langle 0_\text{us}|a^\dagger_\text{acc} a_\text{acc}| 0_\text{us}\rangle \neq 0 \tag{1}\\
N_\text{acc/acc} &= \langle 0_\text{acc}|a^\dagger_\text{acc} a_\text{acc}| 0_\text{acc}\rangle = 0 \tag{2}\\
N_\text{us/us} &= \langle 0_\text{us}|a^\dagger_\text{us} a_\text{us}| 0_\text{us}\rangle = 0 \tag{3}
\end{align}
Where "acc" stands for an accelerated referential with respect to "us". In complete analogy with the Unruh effect, one can think of the electron-on-earth paradox as follows:

*From our point of view, for us landing on Earth, the electron is not accelerating, we are in the (2) situation. From the point of view of a free-falling observer, the electron is accelerating and thus radiate towards the sky, we are in the situation (1)*

We see here clearly that the two situations are inequivalent because the referential in which we see the electron is not the same. This is also an example of the relativity of the concept of particle number. However, For us in free-fall to see the electron's emitted photon, the photon would have to change referential during its travel to us. But as we can see in situation (3) we are always in a vacuum, so it is not possible for us to detect the emitted photon. Another way to think about this is to change referential back to the electron's right before the photon's emission. Since we are then in the same referential as the electron, we are in the vacuum (situation (2)).

To resume what I said here: there is no paradox in the light of the Unruh effect because the two situations described by the electron-on-earth paradox are totally inequivalent. If they were equivalent, there would be a true paradox as one observer is seeing a photon while at the same time another observer is not seeing any photon.